# Why Python garbage collector seems not working with AWSIotMQTTClient instances?

Tags: python, aws-iot

On an embedded Linux machine (running YOCTO PYRO) I run the following test code

```py
def InitializeAWSClient():
    aWSIoTMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient('BlaBla')
for i in range(24):
    InitializeAWSClient()
    time.sleep(5)
```

It should create an instance of AWSIoTMQTTClient every 5 seconds and the instance should be automatically deleted by the garbage collector. BUT I get the memory usage increasing more and more: after 10 loops more then 50Mb of RAM are used.
I'm using the AWS IoT Python SDK downloaded from https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/tree/master/AWSIoTPythonSDK.
Is there anyone who can help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can run `gc.collect()` from the `gc` module but that won't guarantee the memory is released back to the system. However I wasn't able to reproduce your issue on my computer - running the above snippet does not cause the memory to go over 17 MB; perhaps your memory leak comes from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake in submitting the request (I'm very sorry for that since I know the value of the time of the people and I have wasted your time). The problem is not in the increasing of the RAM usage but in the increasing of the CPU usage: more than 50% after 10 loops.

Comment: For CPU usage you can profile your code using cProfile; if you want a graphical representation of the results you can use something like [SnakeViz](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/).

Comment: Thank you Ionut. We will try to use it.